# RC circuit analysis with switch

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, switches

In the following question [image]I couldn't find a way how to find the voltage Vc at time T+.Can you explain to me? How can I find impulsive current due to switch.I don't want complete answer to this question.I found T- as shown .[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should find the equivalent capacitance then find equivalent charge on the capacitor.When you divide them each other ,it will give you the voltage at T(+).[image]